# In Ruby, via Sinatra, how do I get a link within an `li` tag?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am using `erb` and ideally, I would like my html to look like this:

```
<li class="selected"><a href="awesome.html">Look at this awesome page</a></li>
```

Where both the path for the link, and the class for the li are dynamically generated using an instance variable.

Thoughts?

**Edit 1**

If I were using something like Rails, I know I could probably do something like:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:li, nil, awesome_path, :class => "selected") %>
```

But that would produce the opposite effect, where the `<a>` would be outside of the `<li>` and not inside where I want it.

Comment: Would love to get a comment on why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's called a helper:

```
helpers do
    def li_with_a options
        '<li class="' + options[:class] + '"><a href="' + options[:url] + '">' + options[:text] + '</a></li>'
    end
end
```

and from erb:

```
<%= li_with_a :class => 'selected', :url => 'awesome.html', :text => 'Look at this text' %>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Is there anyway I can modify this, to include a dynamically generated `ul` within the `li`?

For instance, right now..I have the static html tags `<li><a href=#>Awsm LInk</a><ul><li>First Item</li><li>Last Item</li></li>`

So in that case, I would like to be able to dynamically generate the child list, using a loop in the view (not the helper), and then once the loop is done close the li.

How can I do that, in an elegant way? 

I guess one way is just to leave out the ending `</li>` tag of the helper, but that seems a bit crude...any other way that ensures I have complete `li` tags?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but the best thing is probably to send the array to the helper and let it iterate them.

Answer (score 3):

Should be as easy as:

```
<li class="<%= @li_class %>">
  <a href="<%= @page_path %>">Look at this awesome page</a>
</li>
```

Of course you have to change the instance variables accordingly.

Comment: This is actually kinda what I had, minus the `li_class`, but I needed more flexibility. I think the helper in the other answer is exactly what I need.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know how complex your needs were. Anyway, when using the helper from the other answer, please use string interpolation (`#{}`) instead of the rather wasteful `String#+` method.

Comment: Done. I usually use that...did you see an indication that I don't somewhere, that you can point out - in case I have missed something?

Comment: No, it was more about the solution posted by pguardiario, I just wanted to advise you not to copy/paste exactly as is :-)

Comment: Oh...my bad...I think I misread you...what would be a better solution, than what he wrote? You mean, rather than doing `'<li class="' + options[:class]`, I do something like: `<li class=#{options[:class]}`...is that what you mean?

Comment: YEs, that's what I mean. Note that if you don't want to escape the double quotes, you can also create strings like this `%{this is a string}`.

Comment: yep, I know. Thanks though :)